# Dynamic fallback for empty translations? - Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

Im using the Mobility gem (v0.4.3 - https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) and Rails 5.2, and at the moment to set fallbacks I have to set up this in the model:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  ....
  extend Mobility
  translates :title, type: :string, locale_accessors: true, fallbacks: { en: :es }
  ....
end
```

The main problem is that the fallback hash is static and in my app the hash could change depending the client configuration.

There is any way to set the fallback hash dynamically?

Comment: I have seen that but it's going to be a nightmare to set it on each view... probably should be a way to set the fallbacks for all the models dynamically

Comment: what I'm looking for is something similar to what I used in the past with the Globalize gem: fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true

Comment: There is not a way to do this but it's a reasonable feature. Why don't you make a feature request as an issue to the github repo? (I'm the author.)

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg done, btw thanks a lot for your work in this gem :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg Is there a good way to achieve this now, with mobility ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the fallbacks while reading

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
 ....
 extend Mobility
  translates :title, type: :string, fallbacks: true
 ....
 end
```

and read like this

```
client.translate(fallback: [:ja, :es])
```